Log axis in ploy_ly for R
I'm trying to make a 3D mesh plot with log x and y axis using plot_ly.
library(plotly)

help_plot_data <- data.frame(A_Conc = rep(c(1:100), times = 100),
                             B_Conc = rep(c(1:100), each = 100))
help_plot_data$Response <- help_plot_data$A_Conc*help_plot_data$B_Conc

plot_model <- plot_ly(
  help_plot_data, x= ~A_Conc, y= ~B_Conc, z = ~Response, 
  type='mesh3d', intensity = ~Response,
  colors= colorRamp(rainbow(5))) %>% 
  layout(plot_model, 
         xaxis = list(range = c(1, 100),
                      type = "log"),
         yaxis = list(range = c(1, 100),
                      type = "log"))
plot_model


Gives me this plot:

I've also tried scale_log_10(), which I couldn't get to work. Any help much appreciated.

Setting the scene in the layout function results in a basic log plot. You will probably want to adjust the tick marks on the x and y axis.
library(plotly)

help_plot_data <- data.frame(A_Conc = rep(c(1:100), times = 100),
                             B_Conc = rep(c(1:100), each = 100))
help_plot_data$Response <- help_plot_data$A_Conc*help_plot_data$B_Conc

plot_model <- plot_ly(
  help_plot_data, x= ~A_Conc, y= ~B_Conc, z = ~Response, 
  type='mesh3d', intensity = ~Response,
  colors= colorRamp(rainbow(5))) |> 
  layout(scene = list(
         xaxis = list(type = "log"),
         yaxis = list(type = "log")))


plot_model


Works a charm. Thanks!
